# Why does string_stream.str() = a_string; compile?

Tags: c++, stringstream, rvalue, istringstream, equals-operator

I can create an `std::istringstream` like so

```
std::istringstream string_stream(inp_string);
```

I can then change the contents of the stream:

```
string_stream.str(std::move(inp_string_2));
```

However, I might accidentally try something like this:

```
string_stream.str() = inp_string_2;
```

This compiles, but will not change the contents of `string_stream`. If you check the return value of `std::istringstream::str()` [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream/str), you will see that the return value is of non-reference type.

I believe that `std::istringstream::str()` is an r-value, and writing it on the left side of the equals sign should give an error, but the following code compiles in MSVC:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>


int main() {
    // Create string stream
    std::string inp_string = "this is a test string";
    std::istringstream string_stream(inp_string);


    // Try to replace the string stream
    std::string inp_string_2 = "a new test string";

    // incorrect:
    string_stream.str() = inp_string_2;            // Expected Error
    string_stream.str() = std::move(inp_string_2); // Expected Error

    // correct:
    // string_stream.str(std::move(inp_string_2));


    // Check contents of string stream
    std::cout << string_stream.str();
}
```

The output is

```
this is a test string
```

#### A Related Example

Below is similar example that will fail to compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


class MyClass {
private:
    std::vector<int> my_vec;

public:
    MyClass(std::vector<int>& vec) : my_vec(std::move(vec)){}

    int operator() (int i) {
        return my_vec[i];
    }
};


int main() {
    std::vector<int> inp = { 1, 2, 3, 4,  5 };
    MyClass my_class(inp);
    my_class(3) = 2;               // ERROR
    std::cout << my_class[3];

}
```

This gives the error

```
error C2106: '=': left operand must be l-value
```

as expected.

Comment: Fundamental and user-defined types are different in this respect. Related note: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next#Notes

Comment: The relation to `stringstream` is a red herring. A much shorter example: `#include <string> int main() { std::string() = "Hello"; }`

Comment: This compiles not only in MSVC. The alternative is returning a `const` object. Also, in C++ there are many more cases where you are allowed to write nonsensical code.

Comment: It only recently became possible for member functions to overload based on rvalue-ness of `*this`.

Comment: The target is about assigning to a `std::string` temporary, but it's the same idea as in your question.

Comment: @cigien Thanks. My question is a duplicate of yours. However, after reading the responses, I am not satisfied by the answers. None of the answers to your question provided a single use-case.

Comment: There *aren't* any use-cases really :) It's just that we *couldn't* restrict assignment to temporaries until C++11, and now it hasn't been considered worthwhile to add that restriction yet.